# SQL query in tables side by side instead of one long table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ajax

I have ajax ReorderList in my wep page,and I get the data from SQL Server.
I would like to add table cells dynamically according to number of records and show the result side by side until for example I have five data in a row and then move to the next row,

any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use a [**DataList**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.aspx) control, and [set the Horizontal layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79k821wc.aspx) to the desired number of cells using the RepeatColumns and RepeatDirection properties.

```
<asp:DataList id="myDataList" runat="server" 
      RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection ="Horizontal" 
      DataSourceID="MySqlDataSource" DataKeyField="SqlKeyFieldName">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <%# Eval("SqlFieldName") %>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```